# List only folder which has no subdirectory only files

Tags: php, directory

How I list only folders which has no subdirectory and contains only images?
Is there any method in php for doing this?

Comment: you can try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php.

Comment: The [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function may come in useful.

Comment: here is a link for you http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dirlist/1/